# OpenPGP Public-Key algorithm

Tags: elliptic-curves, pgp

What means when `pgpdump` shows this kind of algorithm in the Public-Key Encrypted Session Key Packet?

```
New: Public-Key Encrypted Session Key Packet(tag 1)(126 bytes)
    New version(3)
    Key ID - 0xEC661A345473
    Pub alg - Reserved for Elliptic Curve(pub 18)
        unknown(pub 18)
        -> m = sym alg(1 byte) + checksum(2 bytes) + PKCS-1 block type 02
```

What means `m = sym alg(1 byte) + checksum(2 bytes) + PKCS-1 block type 02`?

Which Elliptic-Curve-based operation was made from the sender software?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Pub alg - Reserved for Elliptic Curve(pub 18)
    unknown(pub 18)
```

The output explains `pgpdump` knows this is an [elliptic curve algorithm (which has ID 18)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6637#section-5), but does not understand the exact details (which curve was used, ...). Try `gpg --list-packets` instead which has full support for ECC (requires GnuPG 2.1, binary might also be called `gpg2` on Debian and derivatives).

```
    -> m = sym alg(1 byte) + checksum(2 bytes) + PKCS-1 block type 02
```

These are details of the session key used for the symmetrically encrypted packet that will follow: the symmetric algorithm, a checksum and finally the PKCS-1 encoded session key. From [RFC 4880, OpenPGP, 5.1.  Public-Key Encrypted Session Key Packets (Tag 1)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880#section-5.1):

> The value "m" in the above formulas is derived from the session key
> as follows.  First, the session key is prefixed with a one-octet
> algorithm identifier that specifies the symmetric encryption
> algorithm used to encrypt the following Symmetrically Encrypted Data
> Packet.  Then a two-octet checksum is appended, which is equal to the
> sum of the preceding session key octets, not including the algorithm
> identifier, modulo 65536.  This value is then encoded as described in
> PKCS#1 block encoding EME-PKCS1-v1_5 in Section 7.2.1 of [RFC3447] to
> form the "m" value used in the formulas above.  See Section 13.1 of
> this document for notes on OpenPGP's use of PKCS#1.

Comment: and what means `m**e mod n` ? in the RFC-4880 you linked me? thank you

Comment: @Alexander.It, `m**e mod n` should be $m^e\bmod n$.

Comment: The formula describes the encryption using RSA, for ECC look into [RFC 6637](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6637).

Comment: I also think the same but why not write m^e ? :@