# pgpdump alternative for gnupg 2.x

Tags: elliptic-curves, pgp

I want to see gpg2 key parameters packets. pgpdump v0.32 doesn't support gpg2 (especially elliptic curve cryptography packets) and "gpg2 --list-packets" doesn't show "secret" key parameters.

Is there any way to see (secret) key parameters ([d, q and curve](https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gcrypt/ECC-key-parameters.html#ECC-key-parameters)) of elliptic curve crypto algorithms in gpg2 exported secret subkeys?

Note: I read [OpenPGP Public-Key algorithm](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/28987/openpgp-public-key-algorithm) but this is not my answer.

Comment: Do you have an example of missing parameters in `—list-packets`?

Comment: @eckes I want to see secret parameters like private key "d", with list-packets option and without any other option, gpg2 doesn't show secret packets, my question is about other necessary option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I use `--verbose --list-packets` on an export of a secret key it displays all the fields in the secret key (sub)packets. At least it looks like it is complete.

It does not open key encryption, so I have to export the key with a empty passphrase (unfortunatelly there is no export option for that anymore so I had to edit the key).

In this case it uses a named curve, the curve parameters are publically known and not exported.

```
> gpg.exe --verbose --list-keys
pub   brainpoolP384r1 2017-12-09 [SC]
      971D76C158AFD6D6AC53205327C195C6F0FB0EDA
uid        [ ultimativ ] Bernd Eckenfels (test) <ecki@zusammenkunft.net>
sub   brainpoolP384r1 2017-12-09 [E]

> gpg.exe --export-secret-key > secret.pgp

> gpg.exe" --verbose --list-packets secret.pgp
...
# off=0 ctb=94 tag=5 hlen=2 plen=168
:secret key packet:
        version 4, algo 19, created 1512840291, expires 0
        pkey[0]: 092B240303020801010B brainpoolP384r1 (1.3.36.3.3.2.8.1.1.11)
        pkey[1]: 042B9980A50F01AE91CA7B5A6ABDD350B3FE6BB8E7F44E561FDCB45354BA0D721DA4D9E3DB9B8CD96E248F2099E643E0073649E6D97DB9FCF67B1060F8F36EE0F12F3CEAC68F0D7DAC811DA290693F7620640F87A398901E6D2BDBEA6D4A7251E4
        skey[2]: 40223083F5447B9C109A2F063EAF45FFA7D3DDC48AF71F061B4E95CA475775CF488095D4EDE4109B9539DFD036AE4DB7
        checksum: 1872
        keyid: 27C195C6F0FB0EDA
...
# off=397 ctb=9c tag=7 hlen=2 plen=172
:secret sub key packet:
        version 4, algo 18, created 1512840291, expires 0
        pkey[0]: 092B240303020801010B brainpoolP384r1 (1.3.36.3.3.2.8.1.1.11)
        pkey[1]: 0467F588651ACAB96B80CA052030B3337E8374586C86B3D4386D5569D6C548C0D76662EB112438300B73275FB81809CE6642D3B1878292729B1F3FD1AE2C246AE7064A7B9464446E7A4E0C16B25FD933556371271862C6EEFDFE01087BEEB3CFF9
        pkey[2]: 03010909
        skey[3]: 15FCB0053B11FD8E4E907E9E7ED937F0E226AE0DF4D79D333ED18BF396191628E8A82241BF26B1C1FBD9F5984636A495
        checksum: 19cb
        keyid: 80C1909634D5FC1B
```

18  ECDH public key algorithm   [RFC6637]
19  ECDSA public key algorithm  [RFC6637]

`pkey[0]` is the curve OID. Parameters of the curve are public known and not part of the key format.

`pkey[1]` is the public point (uncompressed format starting with 04 and then two 384bit scalar integers as coordinates).

According to RFC 6637 there is only a single secret algorithm specific parameter for ECDH and ECDSA keys: a MPI scalar. The above example lists them as `skey[2]` for ECDSA main key. In my case is a 0x017f bit long scalar (48bytes).

BTW: If exported with password protected keys, it looks like:

```
# off=0 ctb=94 tag=5 hlen=2 plen=214
:secret key packet:
        version 4, algo 19, created 1512840291, expires 0
        pkey[0]: 092B240303020801010B brainpoolP384r1 (1.3.36.3.3.2.8.1.1.11)
        pkey[1]: 042B9980A50F01AE91CA7B5A6ABDD350B3FE6BB8E7F44E561FDCB45354BA0D721DA4D9E3DB9B8CD96E248F2099E643E0073649E6D97DB9FCF67B1060F8F36EE0F12F3CEAC68F0D7DAC811DA290693F7620640F87A398901E6D2BDBEA6D4A7251E4
        iter+salt S2K, algo: 7, SHA1 protection, hash: 2, salt: 70B08AE0E115EFEE
        protect count: 1507328 (167)
        protect IV:  98 be 19 56 65 43 7c 32 0a ff 4f 21 5b eb 47 af
        skey[2]: [v4 protected]
        keyid: 27C195C6F0FB0EDA
```

The examples have been created with win64 gpg 2.3.2 (libcrypt 1.8.1).

Here is the test key: https://gist.github.com/ecki/8adb287fa64347bfba218a6fd9e21d0f and details.

Comment: Thanks, one question: which version of gpg have you?

Comment: Sorry for the multiple corrections, my hex editor showed the length in hex and confused me. skey[2] is actually printed correctly.

Comment: with gpg 2.1.2 and gpg 1.4.15, I can't see key packets

Comment: I asked another question in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47683104/elliptic-curve-point-multiplication-in-c-with-libgcrypt , can you help me about libgcrypt?

Comment: @gcrypt Sorry, dont have experience with libcrypt programming. But your question does not say what errors you get and what is not working.

Comment: I don't understand context (ctx) objects and I have some memory errors when convert from s-exp to mpi format

Comment: thank you for useful answer, I change my gpg version and now I am enlightened!

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/alex-nitrokey/python-pgpdump can decipher password-protected secret keys (you will have to write a bit of python code though):

````
import pgpdump

with open("key.asc", "r") as f:
    data = pgpdump.AsciiData(f.read(), secret_keys=True, passphrase=None)

for packet in data.packets():
    print(packet)
```
````